# How to show eclipse menu

Tags: eclipse

I did hidden eclipse main menu.
I want to display all item of eclipse menu but i don't know how to do this. Help me.

[image]

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9n.htm
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463693/hide-eclipse-top-main-menu

Comment: How to select "Window > Customize Perspective...." .. My Eclipse IDE haven't main menu because i hidden it.. You can see image i post :(... Sorry use english not good :(

Comment: I see. Maybe you can choose the "Window" using keyboard, like: `Alt+W`? Try it.

Comment: Nothing happened when i press "Alt + W" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    `You could achieve this goto your workspace delete folder
 .metadata folder then open` 
    `eclipse with this workspace and import 
    all projects selecting your workspace folder.`
```

In window option there is show toolbar click and see

Press alt to see window menu

or use `customized perspective`

Comment: Nothing happened when i press "alt"

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the **C/C++ (or Java/PyDev) perspective icon** and choose **Reset** to reset the perspective to default setting.